How to control the dynamic control in reactive form without using change detection for complex forms?
I'm using angular reactive forms where i have some dynomic forms and that are added and removed according to the condition and UI view depends on value change.
Is there is a way so that angular not check all the values every time when the one of the value is change? it just check that value which is change.
I know that Angular performs change detection every time a form control is updated, but in a large complex form, this becomes inefficient according to me


Turn on OnPush change detection strategy so that the change detection firing is reduced. You can trigger change detection manually using cdr.detectChanges()

Instead of listening for valueChanges go for direct DOM events. You can listen to input, change, 'select', etc. When this event is fired trigger your reactive validations/actions using these functions.
 <input formControlName="test" (input)="disableNameWhenFilled()" />


In the second argument of FormGroup, we can supply a AbstractControlOptions, here we can set a property called updateOn, use this flag, to trigger the form change detection lesser, it supports three options "change" | "blur" | "submit"
 this.forma =new FormGroup({
   dato1: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
   dato2: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
   dato3: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
   dato4: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
 },{ updateOn: 'submit' })

Forked Stackblitz Demo

Use debounceTime to reduce the number of form valueChanges firing in your component. You might experience a delay on this one, but for rare scenarios, it comes in handy.
 this.form.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(250).subscribe(() => {
   ...
 });



